# Serializing jackson generated classes

Tags: java, jackson, resteasy

I use jackson (via resteasy) to convert json to a Java object.  I've only defined an interface for the object and jackson generates the implementation automatically.  Great!

Now I'm trying to save the object and restore it later.  My interface extends `Serializable`, so my datastore saves it without complaint.  When it comes time to load it later, though, the generated class definition is nowhere to be found.  I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.generated.my.class.name
```

What are my options for saving and loading objects with class definitions generated by Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe serialize POJO as `java.util.Map` instead? JDK serialization is tightly bound to concrete classes, so it may not work well with Jackson's abstract type materialization (I assume you are using "Mr Bean" module).

Comment: Yes, I gave up on getting this to work automatically.  In the end I just implemented the interface with a simple concrete class backed by a map.